# Zabbix - track config files

Tags: zabbix

I would like to track changes to one config file. The reason for this is that multiple users access it to solve different issues, but every now and then those fixes break something else. diff function in Zabbix shows that a file was changed, but I would like Zabbix to also track what changed. Is there a combination of triggers that would let me do that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you store file checksum or contents in the item? In any case, there is no built-in way to do that, but you can implement it with a script.

If checksum, you will need a way to store the previous version, new version and run  the diff command. The easiest would be a userparameter that would do a diff between a temporary copy of the file and the current copy, then copy the current file over the temporary copy. In this case, you would store diff results directly in an item and your trigger would check that the last value is not an empty string. See https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/userparameters for more information on userparameters.

If you are storing file contents already, presumably you want to reuse them. This would be a bit more complicated, as you would have to kick off the script whenever a new value arrives - maybe a special trigger could kick off an action that would compare the last two values (probably using the API), then push the result in another item that has another trigger. Unless you have a good reason to do it this way, I'd opt for the first approach.

Comment: Ricklv, thank you very much for your answer! When you say "you will need a way to store the previous version", how can I do that? Store 2 files and run diff was my first idea, but I don't have an idea how to do so.

Comment: the next sentence suggests one method :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy off your file

file.txt.copy or something like that. Make this file only writable by zabbix.

Create an item and trigger on zabbix to check when the file was changed (using diff or checksum)

Create a action on zabbix to execute a script that will

1 - diff between file.txt and file.txt.copy and send this diference to your email

2 - Copy file.txt to file.txt.copy so you can do the diff next time the file change.

To reate a action with script.
Create a action on zabbix. Go to "operations" tab. Select "Remote Command" from option.
Choose custom script.
Put the script with the whole path and arg's.

Sample

```
/opt/script/my_script.sh
```

The user zabbix must have permission to ruin the script.

[Zabbix docs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/notifications/action/operation/remote_command)

Comment: Thank you Vitorino, I am able to do everything, but I am having issues with  creating the action. In which part of the Action do I define the script? Please don't refer me to  Zabbix documentation, as it is very lacking in the actions area.

Comment: Changed my answer and there is no lack of information in zabbix documentation.